# i create new route table on my project, but the class not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i create a new route table in order to version control and require it on default table

```
require(__DIR__ . '/Routes/routes_v2.php');
```

then that my new route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v2','middleware' => ['web'],'namespace'=>'v2\Home\Service'],function (){

    //验证码
    Route::post('send', 'ValidateController@sendSMS');
```

then that's my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\v2\Home\Service;

use App\Models\SMS\M3Result;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Model\Home\Members;
use App\Http\Model\Home\MembersAuth;
use App\Http\Tools\SMS\SendTemplateSMS;
use App\Http\Model\Home\TempPhone;
use App\Http\Requests;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


class ValidateController extends CommonController
```

when i run the `php artisan route:list`on my project

```
 [ReflectionException]
  Class App\Http\Controllers\v2\Home\Service\ValidateController does not exis
  t
```

and input the route in url ,they return 500 Internal Server Error
 what problem for my route?

Comment: well, have you checked your `ValidateController` class file name match with class name (ie. `ValidateController.php`)? if so, try to fire a `composer dump-autoload` and check on `/vendor/composer/autoload-classmap.php` (if i'm not wrong, but it should be around there..) whether your ValidateController mentioned.

Comment: add my laravel log

Comment: [2016-12-08 10:11:38] app.ERROR: ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Controllers\v2\Home\Service\ValidateController does not exist in /var/www/enclaveapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:734

Comment: uh... have you tried the `composer dump-autoload` from command line?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to keep your new routes in the same route file as your existing routes?

Comment: @BagusTesa, i run the composer dump-autoload, but it no effect

Comment: @jackel414,yes, I must have a version control.

Comment: Well, the way you're using Route::group and giving it a prefix should already separate it from your existing routes. So putting it in your existing routes file shouldn't create a conflict

Comment: @jackel414 Route::group(['prefix' => 'api','middleware' => ['web'],'namespace'=>'Home\Service'],function (){ that my existing routres, that it's no conflict

Answer (score 0):

My guess, assuming your new routes file is being imported correctly (per my comment, I would advise against creating a "v2" routes file), is that your folder structure does not reflect your namespace. Based on your namespace, Laravel by default will look for the ValidateController in Controllers/v2/Home/Service. Is that where your ValidateController is now?

Also, unless your CommonController class is in the same namespace as the ValidateController, you'll need to import that as well.

Comment: on my v2 folder, i had a CommonController the same namespace with ValidateController

Comment: `namespace App\Http\Controllers\v2\Home\Service;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller\v2;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class CommonController extends Controller
{
    /`

Comment: is your ValidateController in the `app/Http/Controllers/v2/Home/Service/` directory?